# Problem 4.139 from Volkoviskiy, Lunts, Aramanovich

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

$\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^a\varphi\cos b\varphi\,d\varphi
= \frac{\pi\Gamma(a+1)}
{2^{a+1}\Gamma\left(\frac{\;a\,+\,b\;}{2}+1\right)
\Gamma\left(\frac{\;a\,-\,b\;}{2}+1\right)}$, $\;$ if $\;b>a>-1$.

Hint. consider $\int_C\left({z+\frac{1}{z}}\right)^az^{b-1}\,dz$ on an appropriate contour and transform the part on the interval $(-i,i)$ into Euler integrals.

(see pbm 4.139 in the (Russian edition of the) problem book L. I. Volkovyskii, G. L. Lunts, I. G. Aramanovich, J. Berry: A collection of problems on complex analysis [1 ed.] Dover Publications).

Comment: are you sure that this result is right?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Mathematica confirms the identity for $a,b < 100$

Comment: I'm not. I also had doubts about large $b$. But so it stands in the problem book. It is the pbm #850 in the English edition of the book.

Comment: http://advancedintegrals.com/2017/04/integrating-a-function-around-three-branches-using-a-semi-circle-contour/

Comment: The proof in http://advancedintegrals.com/2017/04/integrating-a-function-around-three-branches-using-a-semi-circle-contour/ makes use of logarithms witch is redundant.

Denote the integral $I$. Easy,
$$
I=2^{-a-1}\text{Im}\int_{C}(1+z^2)^az^{b-a-1}\,dz
$$
After showing that integrals over small arcs tend to zero.
\begin{gather*}
I=2^{-a-1}\text{Im}\left[\left((i)^{b-a}-(-i)^{b-a}\right)
\int_0^{1}x^{b-a-1}(1-x^2)^a\,dx\right]\\
=2^{-a-1}\text{Im}\left[\left(e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}(b-a)}- e^{\frac{-i\pi}{2}(b-a)}\right) \int_0^{1}x^{b-a-1}(1-x^2)^{a}\,dx\right]
\end{gather*}